# Missing Template error for json return Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, templates

I have a `locations_controller` and inside I have `#index` and `#show` action. I have a map on `index.html.erb` and when user pans/moves on the map `#show` action should send json data to map to show the listings. I am sending json request to `#show` action. But it returns an error saying;

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template locations/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates"
  * "/Users/emreozkan/Desktop/yedek/Last.1/app/views"
  * "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:48:in 'show'
```

here is the request in `index.html.erb`

```
<script>

    (function ( $ ) {

      $('#map-canvas').mapSearch({
        request_uri: 'locations/show', 
        initialPosition: [ <%= @initlat %> , <%= @initlng %> ],
        filters_form : '#filters',
        listing_template : function(listing){ 
                    return '<div class="listing">'
                      +     '<h3>'+listing.address + '</h3>'
                      +   '<div class="row">'
                      +        '<div class="col-sm-2">'
                      +         '<img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg">'
                      +          '</div>'
                      +        '<div class="col-sm-5">'
                      +           '<p><strong>Address : </strong>' + listing.address+ '</p>'
                      +               '<p>'+'...'+', '+'...'+' '+l'...'+'</p>'
                      +               '<p>Reg Year: ' + '...'+'</p>'
                      +          '</div>'
                      +        '<div class="col-sm-5">'
                      +         '<p><strong>Demo:</strong> '+'...'+'</p>'
                      +         '<p><strong>Demo:</strong> '+'...'+'</p>'
                      +          '</div>'
                      +   '</div>'
                      +  '</div>';
                  },
        marker_clusterer : true
      });
    }( jQuery ));

  </script>
```

And here is my `locations_controller`;

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController

  def index

    if params[:search].present?   
      location = Geocoder.search(params[:search])
      @locations =location[0]

    else
        @locations = Location.all.first
    end
    @initlat = @locations.latitude
    @initlng = @locations.longitude

  end



  def show

    ne_lat = params[:ne_lat].to_f
    ne_lng = params[:ne_lng].to_f
    sw_lat = params[:sw_lat].to_f
    sw_lng = params[:sw_lng].to_f

    mylatlong2 = Location.all


    locs = {'results' => mylatlong2}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json: locs}
    end
  end
end
```

I do not know where I am doing wrong with json request. If you can help me I would appreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line `request_uri: 'locations/show'` in place of `'locations/show'` try using `'/locations/show.json'` instead.

Hope this one helps!